# Force Stop results to populate until a field in form is not blank

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Problem:** I have a form that displays results which works fine.

However, when a users enters a zip code and leaves the miles field blank, it will populate an alert notifying the user to select a miles. When the user closes the alert box, rather not showing the results until that field is satisfied and the search button is clicked once again, it will populate the results before the user has the chance to select a miles.

The following is the form:

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
    <form name="UrgentCareSearch" ng-submit="SearchUrgentCare(searchParam);" novalidate role="form" onsubmit="return checkTextField()">
        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="hospital" ng-model="searchParam.HospitalName" placeholder="Hospital Name" type="text" /></div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option>  
        <option value=""></option>
                      <cfoutput query="HospCityFind">
                      <option value=#officecity#>#officecity#</option>
                    </cfoutput> 
                  </select></div>

        <hr />
        <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important"><strong>* OR Search by Zip code radius *</strong></div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="miles" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" ng-options="mile.value for mile in miles" required>
                         <option value=""></option><option >5</option><option>10</option><option>15</option><option>20</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="input-group-addon">miles</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
            <div class="form-group"><input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group"><input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search"/></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and the following is the js to check miles:

```
function checkTextField() {
    var distance = document.forms["UrgentCareSearch"]["distance"].value;
    var zip = document.forms["UrgentCareSearch"]["zip"].value;
    var empty=false;
    /*if(zip && distance || !zip && !distance){
        return true;
    }else{
        var alertMessage = "Please Select Distance When You Are Entering A Zip Code.";
        alert(alertMessage);
        return false;
    }*/
    if(zip && !distance){
        var alertMessage = "Please Select Distance When You Are Entering A Zip Code.";
        alert(alertMessage);
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;}
```

I thought, the way it is programmed, it will not show the results because do to my functions but it still does.

Is there a way to force the results not to show until that field is entered and the search button is clicked again?

**UPDATE:** I have tried the following to force the results not to appear until miles is selected along with zip code. The following should work but it doesn't work at the start of the form:

```
<div class="form-group"><input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" onclick="return checkTextField()" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" /></div>
```

and here is the validation:

```
function checkTextField() {
    var distance = document.forms["UrgentCareSearch"]["distance"].value;
    var zip = document.forms["UrgentCareSearch"]["zip"].value;
    /*if(zip && distance || !zip && !distance){
        return true;
    }else{
        var alertMessage = "Please Select Distance When You Are Entering A Zip Code.";
        alert(alertMessage);
        return false;
    }*/
    if(zip && !distance){
        var alertMessage = "Please Select Distance When You Are Entering A Zip Code.";
        alert(alertMessage);
        return false; //Does not submit form
    }
    else
        return true;
}
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

// Controller
myApp.controller('demoController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.searchParam = {
    distance: 5 //set the value to the select box
  }
  $scope.miles = [{
    'value': '5'
  }, {
    'value': '10'
  }, {
    'value': '15'
  }, {
    'value': '20'
  }];
}]) 

// directive that converts number-string to number 
myApp.directive('convertToNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        return val != null ? parseInt(val, 10) : null;
      });
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val) {
        return val != null ? '' + val : null;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This works after I enter a hospital name and city. However, at the start of the page, meaning, when the page first loads up, when I enter a zip code and no miles, the alert will not appear and will show the results. I though the if statement in the checktextField would suffice but it appears it does not work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Post the code of the function that call `checkTextField`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir The form has `onsubmit="return checkTextField()"`

Comment: It works correctly for me here: https://jsfiddle.net/mk8f27hL/ Maybe Angular has some effect on it?

Comment: @Barmar how would I determine which part in angular is effecting it?

Comment: Take out the code that loads Angular.

Comment: Maybe get rid of the `ng-submit` attribute.

Comment: @Barmar I have removed the angular and still shows the same results

Comment: @Barmar I have removed the ng-submit and it does prevent the results. However, it will not show any other results. Even if the user selects a miles

Comment: So you're not submitting the form to the server, the `ng-submit` function processes the form in the client? Maybe you need to put the validation in that function instead of using `onsubmit`.

Comment: @Barmar: Can you show me an example on how to do that? I have been trying and no success

Comment: You don't know how to put an `if()` statement in a function?

Comment: @Barmar: Oh, I thought there was something from angular. My apologies

Comment: @Barmar: I removed the onsubmit and used onclick which works fine. However, at the start of the page when you look up by zip code, it does not work. I have uploaded what I have done

Comment: I've told you that I don't know enough about Angular to help any further with this.

Comment: @Barmar My apologies. Just a little frustrated that I have tried many suggestions and it yet to yield the results

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the validation into the `ng-submit` attribute:

```
ng-submit="if(checkTextField()) SearchUrgentCare(searchParam);"
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried that last night and it didnt work. Not sure what is going .

Comment: Question: How would I show the results only when the search button is clicked again. Meaning, once the miles are selected and the zip code has an entry, once the user selects  the submit button again, the results will show. This will only apply if the zip code is entered

Comment: Every time you click the submit button, the `onsubmit` code will run. So if they fill in all the required fields, it will show the results.

Comment: @ Barmar : Yes, I understand that but how would I make it a requirement when the user selects the zip code. Meanign, when the user enters a zip code, the user is forced to enter a mileage and results will not populate when both the mileage and zip code are not empty when user uses the zip code option? Better yet, how would I direct the user to the drop down distance and then show the results once the submit button is clicked

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your validation function should check that both zip and mileage are entered. If they are, it shows the results, otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: @ Barmar: You are absolutely right. I dont get it. I figured if I do a onclick, it should prevent it to work which it does for the most part. I just stick with that and leave it how it is

Comment: I don't use Angular, I was just assuming that the `ng-submit` attribute replaces normal form submission.

Comment: Same here. So we are in the same boat

Comment: I put the wrong function call after the `if()`. I just corrected it, does this work?

Comment: I have tried that. It will not display any results.

Comment: @ Barmar: also tried the follwoing ng-click="if(checktextField()) SearchUrgentCare(searchParam);"

Comment: That makes no sense. You can't put a statement in parentheses in Javascript. Parentheses can only be around expressions.

Comment: Sorry not around the statement.

Comment: @ Barmar: Sorry for bothering you