# How to prevent results to populate when a particular field is empty in Form

Tags: javascript

**Problem:** I would like to the results not to populate when miles drop down box is not selected when the user has entered a zip code. I have tried the following to achieve the results that when the user uses the zip code option and forget to enter mileage drop down, an alert appears letting the user know to select a miles:

```
function checkTextField() {
    var distance = document.forms["UrgentCareSearch"]["distance"].value;
    var zip = document.forms["UrgentCareSearch"]["zip"].value;
    /*if(zip && distance || !zip && !distance){
        return true;
    }else{
        var alertMessage = "Please Select Distance When You Are Entering A Zip Code.";
        alert(alertMessage);
        return false;
    }*/
    if((zip && !distance) && ){
        var alertMessage = "Please Select Distance When You Are Entering A Zip Code.";
        alert(alertMessage);
        return false; //Does not submit form
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

and here is the form:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
    <form name="UrgentCareSearch" ng-submit="SearchUrgentCare(searchParam);" novalidate role="form" onsubmit="return checkTextField()">
        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="hospital" ng-model="searchParam.HospitalName" placeholder="Hospital Name" type="text" /></div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option>  
        <option value=""></option>
                      <cfoutput query="HospCityFind">
                      <option value=#officecity#>#officecity#</option>
                    </cfoutput> 
                  </select></div>

        <hr />
        <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important"><strong>* OR Search by Zip code radius *</strong></div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="miles" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" ng-options="mile.value for mile in miles" required>
                         <option value=""></option><option >5</option><option>10</option><option>15</option><option>20</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="input-group-addon">miles</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
            <div class="form-group"><input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group"><input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search"/></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, the js does not work. The alert does fire but the results still populates.

My question is: Is there another approach to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Didn't you just ask this same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753935/force-stop-results-to-populate-until-a-field-in-form-is-not-blank)? Also, why is this tagged CF? Sounds like it is really a javascript question.

Comment: @Leigh: use you are correct. will remove the tag and no. My question on this if there is another approach on what I did. It appears it never hits return statement. Or it hits the ng-submit and it will always show the result. My question here is if their is another approach where the submit button first checks if the mileage is selected when the zip code is not blank. if not blank, direct the user to select a mileage and then hit submit again once that has been satisfied?

Comment: Maybe update this question with more details to show how it is different and avoid it being closed as a dupe? Because to my caffeine deprived brain it still sounds like a duplicate ;-)